# CancellationToken is not cancelling all tasks

Tags: c#, .net-core

Newbie to TPL in .NET. Trying to understand `CancellationToken` and how they are signaled to cancel an executing Task. The below code only transmits one Task being cancelled where as same token is passed to both Task. My assumption is if the timeout happen on first task and it execute `ctx.Cancel()` I need a little help in understanding why I am only seeing one exception where as both task should be cancelled. What am I missing and how do I ensure both Tasks are cancelled and not taking memory resources.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting application");
        var ctx = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = ctx.Token;
        try
        {
            var task1 = new Program().Run("task1", token);
            var task2 = new Program().Run("task2", token);

            if (!task1.Wait(1000)) 
                ctx.Cancel();

            task2.Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Aggregate Exception occurred");
            foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Main Exception: {e.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finish Application");
            ctx.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private async Task Run(string name, CancellationToken token)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task Cancelled");
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Executing {name} ...");
            await Task.Delay(250, token);                
        }
    }
```

Only one exception is thrown, what happened to other task? Also, `Console.WriteLine("Task Cancelled")` never got executed.

Output:

```
Starting application
Executing task1 ...
Executing task2 ...
Executing task2 ...
Executing task1 ...
Executing task1 ...
Executing task2 ...
Executing task2 ...
Executing task1 ...
Aggregate Exception occurred
A task was canceled.
Finish Application
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. You should call `ex.Flatten().InnerExceptions` take a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.flatten(v=vs.110).aspx) for reference
2. The `Task.Delay` is [throwing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194865(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of your cancellation logic. Try wrapping that in a `try catch` for logging. Alternatively, you could just not pass the `token` to `Task.Delay`.

Comment: If you don't pass the CancellationToken to Task.Delay, you're kind of missing the point of having a CancellationToken.

Comment: @JoeWhite, I suppose you have a point, the suggestion is made in order to ensure the cancellation handling logic is used instead.

Comment: @mrtig this is helpful but does that mean all the tasks are properly terminated once the cancellation token is issued?

Comment: @WahabAkhtar proper cancellation is something that your logic needs to negotiate - whether that’s exiting the loop or throwing an exception. Cancellation is only done if you have logic to handle it, which includes passing the token to ‘Task.Delay’.